# OpenTracker compilation error

Tags: compilation, cc

I want to compile opentracker(https://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker) on my machine osx 10.9. when run "make" command I get this error:

```
cc -c -o opentracker.o -I../libowfat -Wall -pipe -Wextra  -O3 -DWANT_FULLSCRAPE
opentracker.c
opentracker.c:25:10: fatal error: 'io.h' file not found
#include "io.h"
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [opentracker.o] Error 1
```

what is the problem? Is there any way to install io.h through homebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have sorted this out already but i'll put this here for anyone else who has the same problem.

The "-I../libowfat" tells the compiler to include that path in the search path for header files. io.h is part of libowfat which you need to compile opentracker.

You can get libowfat here http://www.fefe.de/libowfat/

Unpack it and place it one directory up from where you are compiling opentracker. Alternatively you can change the -I to point to where you have libowfat unpacked.